# ContextMenu selected item text

Tags: .net

How to Get Selected Item in a "ContextMenu"

```
 ContextMenu popUpMenu;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // build the outputList context menu
            popUpMenu = new ContextMenu();
            popUpMenu.MenuItems.Add("Item 1", new EventHandler(popUpMenu_Click));
            popUpMenu.MenuItems.Add("Item 2", new EventHandler(popUpMenu_Click));
            popUpMenu.MenuItems.Add("-");
            popUpMenu.MenuItems.Add("Item 3", new EventHandler(popUpMenu_Click));
            popUpMenu.MenuItems.Add("-");
            popUpMenu.MenuItems.Add("Item 4", new EventHandler(popUpMenu_Click));
            notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = popUpMenu;
        }

   // this sample works 
    private void popUpMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string popUpMenu_txt = sender.ToString();
        popUpMenu_txt = popUpMenu_txt.Remove(0, 53);

        switch (popUpMenu_txt)
        {
            case "Item 2":
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Item 2");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

  // and this one not? anyone knows what is wrong with this, and how to fix it?
  private void popUpMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            switch (popUpMenu.MdiListItem.MdiListItem.Text)
            {
                case "Item 2":
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Item 2");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all of that stuff to detect which menu item has been pressed,
just try this snippet

```
        var pressedMenuItem = sender as MenuItem;

        string popUpMenu_txt = pressedMenuItem.Text;
        switch (popUpMenu_txt)
        {
            case "Item 2":
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Item 2");
                }
                break;
        }
```

For the second code you stated, you should use popUpMenu.MenuItems

Answer (score 0):

```
void popUpMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MenuItem selected = (MenuItem)sender;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something based on the menu item you can do like this.

```
private void popUpMenu_Click(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    string t = (o as MenuItem).Text;
    MessageBox.Show(t);
}
```